# Filter <select> with other <select> with database mysql and php

Tags: html, jquery, filter, html-select

I have a form and the user have to select the first `<select>` and it will filter the second `<select>` on db and just after show to user.

I've seen it on some sites and I would like to put it on mine

The first `<select>`

```
<select name="area" id="area">
    <option title="" value="">Select ...</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">third</option>
</select>
```

If I select o option with value 1, it will search on MySQL all lines with id=1

```
SELECT * FROM tblarea WHERE id_prof = 1;
```

And this result will make second select

```
<select name="prof" id="prof">
    <option title="" value="">Select ...</option>
    <option value="1">1.1</option>
    <option value="2">1.2</option>
    <option value="3">1.3</option>
</select>
```

While the query is working it will show on `<select>` "Searching ..."

If I am thinking wrong please help me, and give me ideas.

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is

Comment: use jquery ajax function

Comment: It is a job search site so i need to filter, the area and after show the role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dontHaveName suggested, use an Ajax call that will look something like this:

```
$('#area').on('change', function(e) {

  $.ajax({
    url: '/jobs/options/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(e.target).val(),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(opts) {
      $('#prof').html(opts);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
     console.log(err); 
    }
  });

});
```

Some of the Ajax code is from memory, so let me know if you're getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have few items on your select object, I suggest you to load all possibilities into a JavaScript hash. In this case, use your PHP program to create and populate this hash. And once the user change the first select element, you call a function to populate the second select, using something like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<script language=JavaScript>

//new hash is created
var area_prof = new Object();

// hash is being populated
area_prof["f"] = new Array("1.1","1.2","orange");
area_prof["s"] = new Array("2.1","2.2","white");
area_prof["t"] = new Array("3.1","3.2","3.3","hello world");

function populate()
{
var value=document.getElementById("area").options[document.getElementById("area").selectedIndex].value;

while (document.getElementById("prof").options[1])
    {
    document.getElementById("prof").options[1] = null;
    }

for (var i=0; i<area_prof[value].length; i++)
    {
    document.getElementById("prof").options[i+1] = new Option(area_prof[value][i],i);
    }
}

</script>

<select name="area" id="area" onChange=populate()>
    <option title="" value="">Select ...</option>
    <option value="f">First</option>
    <option value="s">Second</option>
    <option value="t">third</option>
</select>

<select name="prof" id="prof">
    <option title="" value="">Select ...</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

But if you really want/need to create another http request to load the second combobox, ajax is what you need:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Best regards,

Eduardo Maia

Comment: unfortunately, i can not load everything, because it is so heavy. But thank you so much!!